# ElasticSearch: Explaining the discrepancy between sum of all document "_size" and "store.size_in_bytes" API endpoint?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm noticing if I sum up the `_size` property of all my ElasticSearch documents in an index, I get a value of about `180 GB`, but if I go to the `_stats` API endpoint for the same index I get a `size_in_bytes` value for all `primaries` to be `100 GB`.

From my understanding the `_size` property should be the size of the `_source` field and the index currently stores the `_source` field, so should it not be at least as large as the sum of the `_size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _size seems to be storing the actual size the source document. When actually storing the source in stored_fields, Elasticsearch would be compressing it(LZ4 default if I remember correctly). So I would expect it to be less size on disk than the actual size. And if the source doesn't have any binary data in it, the compression ratio is going to be significantly higher too.